# Redirecting Request on Device in Access Point Mode

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, router, access-point

I have a Raspberry Pi with a wifi dongle that is configured for Access Point mode (wifi hotspot).

When a user is connected, I want to redirect any url they enter to a specified IP (the devices setup/configuration page). I'm looking for behavior similar to what happens when you connect to a public hotspot at the airport and you have to enter an email or accept "terms & conditions" before you can browse other pages.

Can this be done on the pi's distribution?

Answer (score 8):

You could get this with a small set of `iptables` rules redirecting all traffic to port 80 and 443 your AP's address:

```
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination localhost:80
```

Additionally you should have your HTTP server configured to redirect every unknown URL to its start page (so that if a user enters `http://www.example.com/path/to/specific/site` you don't get a 404 from your AP's webserver).

For guard dog solutions (to get redirected to a specific page on first connect) there exist dedicated software packages like [WiFiDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/).

Comment: my http server is a single page app so I don't think I would have to worry about redirecting traffic back to the start page.

Comment: Hmmm… depeeends.  If it services the same page ignoring the URL you're surely right.  If it's just a _single page_… but you should know better. ;)

Comment: Its is an angular app.. But now that I think about it, and its not running on port 80, so any internal API request wouldn't get redirected by the IP tables right?

Comment: It is still not showing my localhost after connecting with a device to my hotspot. `iptables-save > somefile.bak` shows me that the rules have been added. `iptables -t nat -nvL` shows me that the rules are in place: `Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 3427 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:80
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:127.0.0.1:80
`

Comment: It doesn't allow localhost for me, so I put `127.0.0.1` in it.