# Configure Access Point to Show Splash/Captive Page

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi

I created an access point (on a raspberrypi3, jessie), which I can properly connect to. Now I want to let devices open up automatically a splash page (hosted on localhost) after connecting to my hotspot. *The access point will never forward any traffic in the future, so I'm Ok with blocking all traffic in the rules.*

From [Redirecting Request on Device in Access Point Mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125296/redirecting-request-on-device-in-access-point-mode) & diff. tutorials I believe that this can be done with `iptables`. The devices open up the splash page, if they cannot access some page they originally want to open (I'm not sure with this).

### iptables

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3:522]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:522]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1176:83156]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1114:81204]
COMMIT
```

`iptables -t nat -nvL` :

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 2156 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:127.0.0.1:80
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:127.0.0.1:80

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 19 packets, 2156 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 48 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 48 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

## Question

How can I configure the iptables (what else is required) to have a splash page popping up by devices, after connecting.